# Multi Website or multi Store?

Tags: multistore, magento2.4, multi-website

I want to build a magento 2 site for b2b and b2c. Each side of the business has totally different customers, products, prices, transational emails, shipping methods, payment methods and even taxes. The only thing the two sites have in common is the domain name and I would like the beb site to just be accessible from the home page at domain.com/trade.

My developer is saying I only need to create another store and another store view, but I think I also need to create another website within magento. Who's right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want different prices then its only possible with different website.Becuase price is Global attribite so you can't set store wise or store view wise.

You must need to create 2 website, 2 store and 2 store view.